# dynamically adding controls to linear or grid layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

For the record, a long time programmer, but very new to android development.  Basically trying self learn.  I have hit a road block, have research and tried variations on things I've found, but am really stuck.

I want to create a row of controls this is dynamically created when I tap on a button (Set).  This row would be added to the bottom of each subsequent row

[Picture of what a row of controls would look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGDVw.jpg)

I've was able to get the program to add a layout to a scrollview and achieve the goal of adding dynamically a row, but I cannot get the textview to size out correctly.  I've tried layoutparam, setwidth with no luck.  The text gets wrapped no matter what I do.

[Picture of running app, rows added, TextView not sizing correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGeXb.jpg)

I tried a linearlayout, but that just overlays and even with just text, the textview remains the same size.

I am trying to get the dynamic creation to match the "hardcoded" layout I did to see how it would look.  Specifically, what am I missing to size the TextView and or any of the other controls (view objects?) in a row.

Here is my view xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="New"
            android:id="@+id/btnNew"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Open"
            android:id="@+id/btnOpen"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Save"
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </GridLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="367dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/grdEntry">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/label_time"
            android:id="@+id/lblTime"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="147dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_gaits"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:focusable="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/label_Gait"
            android:id="@+id/lblGait"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="124dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtSelected"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:numeric="integer" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Set"
            android:id="@+id/btnSet"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true" />

    </GridLayout>
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/my_root">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the original xml I created to help me visualize what I wanted when I created the same thing dynamically.

```
<GridLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_pointer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="232dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Canter - 99 min"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="79dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Del"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="2" />
```

Here is the function that attempts to create a row consisting of an image, a textview and a button (I've kept in the comments to show what I've tried)

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void buildDisplayLine(int count) {

        // create a layout params to define how we add

//        GridLayout.LayoutParams gridParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
//        gridParams.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
//        gridParams.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
//        gridParams.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams imgLayout =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        // create a grid layout to add controls
        GridLayout newGrid = new GridLayout(this);
        newGrid.setId(100 + count);
        newGrid.setColumnCount(3);

//        LinearLayout newGrid = new LinearLayout(this);
//        newGrid.setLayoutParams(imgLayout);

       // newGrid.setVerticalGravity(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        //create an image control
        ImageView newImage = new ImageView(this);
        newImage.setLayoutParams(imgLayout);

        newImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pointer);
        newImage.setId(count + 200);


        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_gaits);
        TextView textGait = (TextView)spinner.getSelectedView();
        String gtResult = textGait.getText().toString();

        TextView txtTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSelected);
        String tmeResult = txtTime.getText().toString();
        String display = gtResult + " - " + tmeResult + " min";

        txtTime.setText("");

        // create a text view control


        TextView newText = new TextView(this);
        newText.setLayoutParams(imgLayout);
        newText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        Resources r = getResources();
        int pc = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 332, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        newText.setWidth(pc);
        //newText.getLayoutParams().width = toPixels(432);
        newText.setPadding(toPixels(15), 0, 0, 0);
       // newText.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
        newText.setText(display);
        newText.setId(300 + count);

        // create a new button
        Button newButton = new Button(this);
        newButton.setLayoutParams(imgLayout);

        newButton.getLayoutParams().height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        newButton.getLayoutParams().width = toPixels(79);
        newButton.setText("Del");
        newButton.setId(400 + count);

        // now add to the original grid layout

        newGrid.addView(newImage);
        newGrid.addView(newText);
        newGrid.addView(newButton);

        LinearLayout my_root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_root);
        LinearLayout A = new LinearLayout(this);
        A.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        my_root.addView(newGrid);

        spinner.requestFocus();


    }
```

Comment: Did you get this worked out?

Comment: I did get this worked out, but the answer regarding LayoutInflater is something I am also going to try.  

What I did was to remove the LayoutParam object I created that had the WRAP_CONTENT constants, these two lines:

        newText.setLayoutParams(imgLayout);
        newText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

and that allowed me to adjust the size.  I was having issues trying to get the image to be at the bottom of the local gridlayout, but I gave up on that for now and took it out.  Once past the UI issues I could get going on logic layers.

Comment: Ok, great. If the answer is helpful, don't forget to upvote & accept! Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `LayoutInflater` to inflate your XML, set the values, and add the view? Something like this:

```
GridView newGrid = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_row, null);
newGrid.setId(100 + count);
...
my_root.addView(newGrid);
```